# Issue with mocking Class<T> instance of Abstract Class

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have an abstract class which i am trying to test:

```
public abstract class ABC<T, ID extends String>  implements B<T, ID>{
    //has an instance variable
    protected Class<T> paramClass;
```

I am trying to write a unit-test case for:

```
ABC.somethod(){

    // logic Use the paramClass here
}
```

I am not able to mock the `paramClass`; it is always `null`.

Code I tried:

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {

      ABC abc=Mockito.mock(ABC.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
      ReflectionTestUtils.setField(abc , "paramClass",  any(Class.class)); 
}
```

Comment: Tried with specific instance of class as well

Comment: I am not sure if you actually need mocking to test an abstract class. Wouldn't it be easier to create a class extending your abstract class for the test? Not all problems should be solved in the same way. Just because Mockito is there doesn't imply we always have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I could get this working as

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(abc, "paramClass", Object.class);
```

Comment: This is not the best option. Please, show us what have you tries so far. How does your test looks?